Dryer drum glide severe uneven wear
On my Kenmore electric dryer model 417.81042000, I replaced the upper drum glide and lower felt glide about 2.5 years ago. Today the dryer snagged some clothing.
Opening up the front, I see the left glide plate is untouched, center glide plate badly worn, and right glide plate worn to the point that it broke off. The felt is clearly more worn on the right too. Obviously I need to replace the glide assembly again, but I wonder why the wear ended up so uneven, and if there is a reasonable thing to do to address that. (I did replace the rear bearing a year ago, but in any case I don't see how the rear bearing could do much for front alignment.)
Photo here:

Any suggestions appreciated!
Peter
